# Milter service needs transport:endpoint instead of "/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"

Tags: postfix, dkim, socket, milter

I have set postfix with milter based on this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy

But then posptfix reported that it can't connect to milter on that socket

I changed socket to in postfix `main.cf` to :

```
    smtpd_milters = /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
    non_smtpd_milters = /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

and opendkim `/etc/default/opendkim` to:

```
SOCKET="local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock" # default
```

Now i get following warning and my mails are not signed:

```
Oct 28 18:45:12 localhost postfix/cleanup[22881]: warning: Milter service needs transport:endpoint instead of "/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the error, the value of parameter `smtpd_milters` and `non_smtpd_milters` wasn't correct. The right one is

```
smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

As stated in [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#smtp-only-milters)

> The general syntax for listening sockets is as follows:
>
> **unix:pathname**
>
> Connect to the local UNIX-domain server that is bound to the specified pathname. If the smtpd(8) or cleanup(8) process runs chrooted, an absolute pathname is interpreted relative to the Postfix queue directory.
>
> **inet:host:port**
>
> Connect to the specified TCP port on the specified local or remote host. The host and port can be specified in numeric or symbolic form.

Comment: Oct 30 22:24:34 localhost postfix/cleanup[25386]: warning: connect to Milter service unix:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

And I can see the opendkim.sock in /var/run/opendkim

Comment: Well, that's another problem. See here for some suggestions http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74477/postfix-smtpd-warning-connect-to-milter-service-unix-var-run-opendkim-opendki

Comment: What's the difference between "local" and "unix" keywords in a path to a unix socket?